# bash script to automate searching for a string in code including sub-folders

Tags: shell, grep, head, tail, cat

I have been using a combination of tail, head and grep to print out code that is relavant to me. It helps me find functions and get straight to the point. I do this about 30 to 40 times a day so I thought i'd ask for some assistance on this since I am not good with sh scripting.

The command format I'd eventually like is something like  giveme "searchstring" -nn  << where nn is the number to give to head. err.. moving on

Below is what I am currently doing

```
grep -rl searchitem ./
cat ./filename | grep -n searchitem
tail -n +line ./filename | head -numberoflinestodisplay
```

Example:

```
jezzy@forum:/var/www/sgs# grep -rl insert_into_selectbox ./
./bin/ext/js/functions_edit.js
./src/ext/js/functions_edit.js

jezzy@forum:/var/www/sgs# cat ./bin/ext/js/functions_edit.js | grep -n insert_into_selectbox
195:    for (key in data) insert_into_selectbox(selectbox, data[key], key, 0);
232:        insert_into_selectbox(selectbox, data[key], key,1);
273:    for (key in data) if (key!="_overload_") insert_into_selectbox(selectbox, data[key], key, 0);
289:function insert_into_selectbox(selectbox,text,value,selected) {
323:      insert_into_selectbox(id,right.value,right.value,1);
334:      insert_into_selectbox(id,options_right[i].text,options_right[i].value,1);
```

Then I choose one of the greps that works for me. I do not mind if the bash script does it for all occurrences of grep. It'll teach me to be more specific with my searches.

```
jezzy@forum:/var/www/sgs# tail -n +289 ./bin/ext/js/functions_edit.js | head -30
function insert_into_selectbox(selectbox,text,value,selected) {
  if (text=="" || value=="") return;
  var obj = getObj(selectbox);
  var index = _selectbox_find(obj, value);
  if (index == -1) {
        index = obj.options.length;
        obj.options[index] = new Option(text,value);
  }
  if (!obj.multiple && selected) obj.options[index].selected = true;
}
```

I think I could figure it out if I knew how to get all instances of the items found.

Merci and Thanks

Comment: Please see my answer. Also, are you really wanting to show the lines in the textfile without matching patterns? `tail -n +line ./filename | head -numberoflinestodisplay`

Comment: @konsolebox I am not matching the pattern, i am simply showing x number of lines after the line that grep -n finds the string in. since I do not know how long the function is, I say, show me say 30 lines of the file after $TAILLINES

Comment: @konsolebox Still using this on a daily basis! Thanks for your help with the script!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT="./"

read -ep "Enter search directory [$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT]: " SEARCHDIR
[[ $SEARCHDIR =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && SEARCHDIR=$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT

for (( ;; )); do
    read -p "Enter search item: " SEARCHITEM
    read -p "Enter number of lines to display: " NUMLINES

    readarray -t MATCHEDFILES < <(exec grep -rl "$SEARCHITEM" "$SEARCHDIR")

    echo "Please select a file to search into. Press C to cancel, or X to exit."

    select FILE in "${MATCHEDFILES[@]}"; do
        if [[ -n $FILE ]]; then
            readarray -t MATCHEDLINES < <(exec grep -n "$SEARCHITEM" "$FILE")
            echo "Please select starting line."
            select LINE in "${MATCHEDLINES[@]}"; do
                if [[ -n $LINE ]]; then
                    LINENUM=${LINE%%:*}
                    tail -n "+$LINENUM" "$FILE" | head -n "$NUMLINES"
                elif [[ $REPLY == [cC] ]]; then
                    break
                elif [[ $REPLY == [xX] ]]; then
                    break 3
                fi
            done
        elif [[ $REPLY == [cC] ]]; then
            break
        elif [[ $REPLY == [xX] ]]; then
            break 2
        fi
    done
done
```

New version:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT="./"
NUMLINES_DEFAULT=10

for (( ;; )); do
    until
        read -ep "Enter search directory [$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT]: " SEARCHDIR
        [[ $SEARCHDIR =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && SEARCHDIR=$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT
        [[ -d $SEARCHDIR ]]
    do
        echo "Please enter a valid directory."
    done
    SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT=$SEARCHDIR

    until
        read -p "Enter search item: " SEARCHITEM
        [[ ! $SEARCHITEM =~ ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]
    do
        echo "Please enter a valid search item."
    done

    until
        read -p "Enter number of lines to display [$NUMLINES_DEFAULT]: " NUMLINES
        [[ $NUMLINES =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && NUMLINES=$NUMLINES_DEFAULT
        [[ $NUMLINES =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ && NUMLINES -gt 0 ]]
    do
        echo "Please enter a valid number of lines."
    done
    NUMLINES_DEFAULT=$NUMLINES

    readarray -t MATCHEDFILES < <(exec grep -rle "$SEARCHITEM" "$SEARCHDIR")

    P1="Please select a file to search into. [ENTER = show list again, C = cancel, X = exit]: "
    P2="Please select starting line. [ENTER = show list again, C = cancel, X = exit]: "

    PS3=$P1

    select FILE in "${MATCHEDFILES[@]}"; do
        if [[ -n $FILE ]]; then
            readarray -t MATCHEDLINES < <(exec grep -ne "$SEARCHITEM" "$FILE")
            if [[ ${#MATCHEDLINES[@]} -eq 0 || ! ${MATCHEDLINES[0]} =~ ^[[:digit:]]+: ]]; then
                echo "No matching lines were extracted. Perhaps file is a binary."
            elif [[ ${#MATCHEDLINES[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
                LINENUM=${MATCHEDLINES[0]%%:*}
                echo "----------------------------------------"
                tail -n "+$LINENUM" "$FILE" | head -n "$NUMLINES"
                echo "----------------------------------------"
            else
                PS3=$P2

                select LINE in "${MATCHEDLINES[@]}"; do
                    if [[ -n $LINE ]]; then
                        LINENUM=${LINE%%:*}
                        echo "----------------------------------------"
                        tail -n "+$LINENUM" "$FILE" | head -n "$NUMLINES"
                        echo "----------------------------------------"
                    elif [[ $REPLY == [cC] ]]; then
                        break
                    elif [[ $REPLY == [xX] ]]; then
                        break 3
                    fi
                done

                PS3=$P1
            fi
        elif [[ $REPLY == [cC] ]]; then
            break
        elif [[ $REPLY == [xX] ]]; then
            break 2
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: i think you've missed up the tail -n **+**## works, when i add a + sign, it starts from the top of the file rather than the end of it, so it actually starts from the line that grep returned.

Comment: i've changed the following in your code  SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT="./"   and   tail -n +"$TAILLINES" "$FILE" | head -n "$NUMLINES", however I need a search function to grab the numbers before the first instance of : in the grep -n output, and those numbers would become the variable "$TAILLINES" for that file.

Comment: @Faruq I see I made the update. If it works for you well please accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left of it. Post back if there's anything missing.

Comment: @Faruq The numbers are pretty many. How do select the number to be used for TAILLINES? Or are we going to count the output?

Comment: hi konsolebox, I dont actually know the taillines element when i submit the query, that is what grep -n does for me, give me the line number where i want to start at. please see my previous comment. $TAILLINES would not be supplied by me, but the script would pick it up from the output of grep -n

Comment: Yes but I mean among the outputs of `grep -n`. As you can see there are many numbers produced out of many lines. How do you choose which number to use for tail? And I don't mean interactively with the `select` command. I just mean how do we process those numbers in the code to be used for `tail`. Is it the number in the last line of the output of `grep -n`?

Comment: @Faruq Sorry I think I now know what you mean. Please see update.

Comment: works almost perfectly except two things, I still have to enter the LINENUM, this should be automaticall parsed from the ######:filename  secondly, after I display enter LINENUM and want to exit with X, it doesnt.

Comment: whats cool is at the #? I can quickly switch between the files, but I'd love to have an exit option there.

Comment: its broken somewhere at Please select the starting line.. doesn't go beyond that. I'd like it to select the starting line itself. It does exit properly though

Comment: @Faruq It's working you just have to type the number. What error do you get?

Comment: I hope you could just try copying everything again instead of patching the contents of an existing script. Perhaps there's something that you missed. I actually have no clue why it's not working for you and that's all I can help. Good luck.

Comment: hi i did copy and paste the whole thing, I wanted to use your example cuz frankly it was more like an app and let me choose what to do, here is the output i get from your script ./konsolebox.sh 
Enter search item: function dbselect
Enter number of lines to display: 10

Please select a file to search into. Press C to cancel, or X to exit.
1) ./bin/core/classes/select.php
2) ./bin/core/classes/modify.php
#? 1
Please select starting line.
1) 123:static function dbselect($params,$vars=array(),$ticket=false) {
#? 123
#? 123
#? 123
#? ^C

Comment: LINENUM="${MATCHEDLINES[@]/:*/ }"

Comment: got it to work using your code, please edit your answer to give you the correct answer.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT="./"

read -ep "Enter search directory [$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT]: " SEARCHDIR
[[ $SEARCHDIR =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]] && SEARCHDIR=$SEARCHDIR_DEFAULT

for (( ;; )); do
    read -p "Enter search item: " SEARCHITEM
    read -p "Enter number of lines to display: " NUMLINES

    readarray -t MATCHEDFILES < <(exec grep -rl "$SEARCHITEM" "$SEARCHDIR")

    echo "Please select a file to search into. Press C to cancel, or X to exit."

    select FILE in "${MATCHEDFILES[@]}"; do
        if [[ -n $FILE ]]; then

Comment: readarray -t MATCHEDLINES < <(exec grep -n "$SEARCHITEM" "$FILE")
                    LINENUM="${MATCHEDLINES[@]/:*/}"
                    tail -n "+$LINENUM" "$FILE" | head "-$NUMLINES"
        elif [[ $REPLY == [cC] ]]; then
            break
        elif [[ $REPLY == [xX] ]]; then
            break 2
        fi
    done
done

Comment: On my original version since we already used `select` and not `read` the one you had to type was supposed to be the number generated on the left, not the one on the item itself. e.g. `Please select starting line. 1) 123:static function dbselect($params,$vars=array(),$ticket=false) { #? 123 #? 123 #? 123 #?` Instead of `123`, the one you had to press instead was supposed to be `1`.

Comment: I tried your version, see update. It seems to give me a syntax error when more than 1 line is matched e.g. `tail: +7 9: invalid number of lines`.

Comment: @Faruq That's exactly the same as the one I tried. And it would give an error if matches are two or more lines since it would appear as `+(number)(space)(number)` which is an invalid syntax to tail.

Comment: I hope you could just reconsider the original version.

Comment: unexpected end of file line 45

Comment: @Faruq Updated and tested. Enjoy the script.

Comment: she's a beaut. thanks, works great. I wanted to report when its saved me hours and hours of work, instead I end up playing with it more than I should. She makes my work more interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should be do what you look for, if I understand it correctly:

```
# Usage: giveme searchstring [numlines]

find . -type f -exec awk -v n=${2:-10} '
/'"$1"'/ {
  printf("==== %s ====\n",FILENAME);
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%4d: %s\n",FNR,$0);
    getline
  }
}' {} +
```

Comment: You are welcome. Is this script doing what you expect ? If not, please tell what is missing.

Comment: It is exactly what I expect, though if I may be frank, the layout konsolebox had presented just sort of makes it more fun to navigate through different files. You were on the money.